# wordpress bloginfo() outside wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use `bloginfo()` of `wardpress` outside wordpress directory.

Say

```
|_index.php (here I want to use bloginfo)
|_wordpress/
|  |-wp-content
|  |-...
```

I have tried this:

```
    <?php require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/KPR website/updates/wp-includes/general-template.php' ); ?>

    <script src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I have got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\xampp2\htdocs\website\updates\wp-includes\general-template.php on line 1315
```

Since I have not modified `general-template.php`, so I think I need to add more require phps, Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call the `wp-load.php` file outside from your wordpress directory then you can use all the wordpress related functions from outside wordpress.

Because `wp-load.php` is the main file that load all the wordpress related files.